# Power to elements in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a question about being able to bring some number to the power of an element in a matrix.
I know that, if A is a matrix, then one could write A.^2 to take the square of each number in that matrix. My question is, is there any way to something like: B=2.^A, such that the resulting matrix B is the same size as A, and each element in that matrix is equal to 2 to the power of the corresponding element in A?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You already answered yourself! Use `B = 2.^A`.

For example:

```
>> A = [1 2; 3 4]
A =
     1     2
     3     4
>> B = 2.^A
B =
     2     4
     8    16
```

You could also use `power(2,A)`, which is the same thing.

Matlab is a very interactive platform, so feel free to experiment and see for yourself if something works or not. In this case your intuition was correct.